# classes of jar file cannot be imported in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I created a jar file from a bunch of java files. Folder structure was `org/ax/redis`. I used the command `jar cvf jedis.jar org/*`. Then I imported this jar file in my netbeans project. Then when I tried importing classes from it, by writing `import org.ax.redis.*`. However,  netbeans shows error that no such package exists.

Now I opened another jar file of log4j to see how it is from inside. Only difference was in manifest file. It had a bunch of directives like `Name: org/apache/log4j/`. So I created a manifest file for my jar file by including `Name: org/ax/redis/`. Used this command to add manifest information in my jar jar `cvfm jedis.jar META-INF/manifest.txt org/*`. Still nothing works. Please help me

Comment: Did you create the jar file from `.java` files or `.class` files? A jar file with just source code in can't be used as a library... Could you show what happens if you run `jar tvf jedis.jar`?

Comment: I hit the command you specified, it is showing me a list of all the .java files inside the jar file. Yes, how dumb of me to not notice biggest difference in that log4j's jar file and mine. Theirs was having all .class files.

Comment: Do you want me to add that as an answer, or are you going to delete the question?

Comment: ohh please add answer. I like to keep all questions I asked, as a review list, however stupid they maybe ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jar files typically contain class files (the results of compilation) rather than *source* files (*.java). While some jar files may contain both, only the class files are available to compile or run against (e.g. using `-cp library.jar`).

So basically, before you build your jar file, you need to compile your code - and then include the class files in the jar file. If you include the source files as well (in the same directory structure) then some IDEs may be able to detect that, which can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Even If u don't generate .class file , the package still can be imported and it won't show any compilation error(If U don't specify any particular class) . However when U try to use a particular class function of that package , it will throw an error .